# Read out some Term from unstructerd Information

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a list of file names. There are about 1 million lines.
In these lines I have a value starting with 58. This value. Starting with 58 and all following numbers I want to read out. Usually it is 8 characters. However, it can also be 9.

The names of the files are very different.

I was thinking about search/find functions or with part but unfortunately I'm not very familiar with Excel.

```
010 AHKG100 58098085 70085-DIS-0082.pdf
002 AHMQ32X32 58098524.pdf
AHSG160-58098564(=A-3129)_01.dwg
003 MVTA_78_ 58098861.pdf
```

These are some variant of file names

The execpted result is as followed, in a new column:

```
58098085
58098524
58098564
58098861
```

Comment: Is it possible to have `58` showing more than once in a string such as `058 MVTA_58_ 58098861.pdf`?

Comment: Hey
Yes, it is possible

`001  AHGL320X190 58054687 60058_01.pdf (In the End by 60058)`

`001 AHAS200-58100769(B-2058).dwg (in the End by 2058)`

`058 AHBQ250×35°58039773.xls (At the beginning)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data starts from cell `A1`, in cell `B1` enter the following **array formula**:

```
=LARGE(IFERROR(--MID(A1,FIND("58",A1,ROW($Z$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(A1)))),{8,9}),0),1)
```

You **MUST** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar otherwise they will not function correctly. Then you can simply drag the formula down to apply across.

[image: Demo]

> The logic is to use **FIND** function to find the starting point of `58` in the string, and then use **MID** function to return the `8-Character` or `9-Character` from the string and use `--` to check if they are numerical values, if not use **IFERROR** function to return `0` instead. Lastly use **LARGE** function to return the largest numeric value from the range, which should only contain the value number and `0` (if there is any).

**EDIT #2**

You can also use the following two formulas which does not require to be entered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--MID(A1,FIND("58",A1,ROW($Z$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(A1)))),{8,9}),1)
```

> This one is essentially the same as the first one but replaced **LARGE+IFERROR** with **AGGREGATE** which is able to ignore error values in the range.

or

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--MID(A1,ROW($Z$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(A1))),{8,9}),1)
```

> This one directly extracting every `8-character` and `9-character` sub-strings from the main string, then use `--` to check if the sub-string is a numerical value, and lastly use **AGGREGATE** to return the largest value from the range.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: @MCH you are welcome. I just edited my answer to include two more formulas which does not need to be entered by **CSE** but essentially they are all array formulas. Check them out and pick the one that suits you the most. Cheers :)